# Extracting the forever ID of a nodeJS instance using grep

Tags: node.js, grep, forever

I'm new to shell scripts and I'm not having much luck with it. How would I extend the following snippet to just get the number between the `[` and `]` ?

```
$ forever list | grep app.js
--> data:   [0] LxSl node    app.js 26017   49833 /Users/username/.forever/LxSl.log 0:0:0:0.57
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe it to `awk '{print $3}'}`, that'll give you `[0]`
To remove the brackets, you can e.g. use `tr -d []`

Everything can also be done from within awk, using `gsub`. Then there is `sed`...

```
...| awk '{print $3}' | tr -d []
0

...| awk '{gsub(/\[|\]/, "", $3);print $3}'
0
```

Comment: Another awk solution that uses `[` and `]` as field separators: `awk -F '[][]' '{print $2}'`

Comment: nice to see you again @glenn (almighty), I missed your corrections to my awk-snippets :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to do this, an example:

```
$ echo "--> data:   [0] LxSl node    app.js 26017   49833 /Users/username/.forever/LxSl.log 0:0:0:0.57"|sed -e "s/[^[]*\[\([0-9]\)\].*/\1/"
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep:  `... | grep -Po '(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])'`